# VScode markdown preview image size control - pandoc compatible?

Tags: css, image, visual-studio-code, markdown, pandoc

Is there some VScode extension that allows image size control in this form?

```
![caption](image.png){ width=whatever }
```

That is the form that is used to get Pandoc to control image size in its output. In this case I'd like to use VSCode - one of my favorite tools - to compose markdown destined for docx output. I've got the Pandoc part working, I'd just like be able to get the previewing to work better in VScode. There might be an extension that does this, but there are zillions of markdown extension for VSCode so who knows.

An alternative would be if there custom css code that would do this, but my css knowledge is not sufficient to know if this is even possible.